# Warning include TestCase phpunit in Magento project

Tags: magento, phpunit

I'm using phpunit for testing in a magento's project.
The issues is that I got this directory inside magento:

```
magento/
-tests/
--integration/bootstrap.php
---Training/
----Example/
-----Helper/DataTest.php
```

So, I got a bootstrap.php, inside this file I turn off warnings for my testing:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../app/Mage.php';
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();

$handler = set_error_handler(function () {});
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) use ($handler)
{
    if (E_WARNING === $errno
        && 0 === strpos($errstr, 'include(')
        && substr($errfile, -19) == 'Varien/Autoload.php'
    ) {
        return null;
    }
    return call_user_func($handler, $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline);
});
```

If this code is inside of DataTest.php inside the function setUpBeforeClass(), everything is ok, but when I create bootstrap.php and execute in console:

```
phpunit --bootstrap tests/integration/bootstrap.php tests/integration/
```

I got the following answer:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(PHPUnit\Extensions\Story\TestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94' in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 245

Exception: Warning: include(PHPUnit\Extensions\Story\TestCase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\wamp\www\magento\lib\Varien\Autoload.php on line 94 in C:\wamp\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\functions.php on line 245
```

I got phpunit in my local server in bin\php\php5.5.12 (in Windows) and I can access in any directory.

So, I don't understand what's going on... because I do not need to modify the core of magento to disable warnings.

Someone can help me to understand?
Thanks for all!!
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your autoloader is trying to load classes it is not responsible for.

Comment: Thanks! And it's true, the autoloader that I call is wrong. :)